# How do I pull left & right the <ul> tag - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

If I put the `class="nav nav-pills"` before the `class="pull-right"` it dosen't work. So, how I could resolve this problem .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
       <style type="text/css">
              <?php include('style.css'); ?>       
       </style>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

     <body>
        <div class="nav " >
          <div class="container">

            <ul  class="pull-left" class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist" >
              <li><a href="rub1ck.php">About Us</a></li>  
              <li><a href="#">Expertise</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">work</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul  class="pull-right" class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist" >

              <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a href="login.php"class="btn btn-default" role="button" >Login</a></li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

    <div class="container">
      <h2>Log in</h2>
      <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="username">Username:</label>
          <input type="username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks for the help .
This was wen I first learned Html :))

Comment: Attaching a JS fiddle would be great!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must have the class name in the same class tag, like this:

```
 <ul  class="nav nav-pills pull-left" role="tablist" >
```

this way is not gonna work

```
 <ul  class="pull-left" class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist" >
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/153/

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills pull-left" role="tablist" >
  <li><a href="rub1ck.php">About Us</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#">Expertise</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">work</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right" role="tablist" >
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="login.php"class="btn btn-default" role="button" >Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can u try putting the classes like this

class="pull-left nav nav-pills"

Having two class attributes in the same tag is not supported as far as i know...